# moving a Drupal installation - what configuration changes required?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess

I would like to move a test Drupal installation from

/opt/lampp/htdocs/corporate/internet

to

/corporate/internet

What corresponding changes changes do I have to make in .htacess, settings.php and/or other settings?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on that how your `sites/` directory is set up. If you just have a `default` directory within, they you really should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, you don't have to make changes.  This is because Drupal installations tend to be set up to use relative paths that will be valid no matter where in the system it is.  You may want to do a quick search of any custom code for the string /opt/lampp/htdocs to see if someone didn't do something relatively, but any other contrib code should work fine.

As Jubal mentions, sites set up in the sites directory may need renaming if you're going to be using a different URL to access the site - if you're moving from devel.site.com to www.site.com, and you have a sites/devel.site.com directory, then you're probably going to want to copy that directory to sites/www.site.com.  On the other hand, if you're using sites/default for your site, or if you're not changing the url at all, then this isn't a problem.

Do note that the .htaccess in the root directory of Drupal is very important for Drupal to work, and that doing a simple cp -R of the directory will not copy the .htaccess, so make sure you copy that.  (.htaccess files in sub-directories, like sites/default/files, will be fine, it's just this one in the root.)

And finally, check your file permissions after you move the files.  You'll especially want to make sure that the file permissions for the files and tmp directories are correct so that people can properly upload files.  (This may not be important - but it's something to check nonetheless.)